# How can I declare a function with a parameter that can be either (Int, Int) or Maybe (Int, Int)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to write a function whose third parameter can be an `(Int, Int)` or a `Maybe (Int, Int)`. Is this possible?

```
randomFunction :: [Char] -> [[Int]] -> Either (Int, Int) Maybe (Int, Int) -> Bool
```

Comment: `Either (Int, Int) (Maybe (Int, Int))`

Comment: …or you actually want to define a type class with two implementation

Comment: You might consider only accepting `(Int, Int)`, and let whoever might provide a `Maybe (Int, Int)` use the `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` instances to lift your function as necessary. (This requires changing the argument order, to `(Int, Int) -> [Char] -> [[Int]] -> Bool`, though.)

Comment: This strikes me as feeling like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). _Why_ do you want to do this? `Maybe (Int, Int)` already provides an option. Does the return value really need to be wrapped up in another option type? If we actually verbalize this, it might sound like: "This value is either an `(Int, Int)` or it's an `(Int, Int)` _or_ it's nothing."

Comment: The type `Either (Int, Int) (Maybe (Int, Int))` is isomorphic to `Maybe (Bool, Int, Int)`. I wonder is this is the type you actually need, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for the thing you ask is:

```
Either (Int, Int) (Maybe (Int, Int))
```

But this is unlikely to be the idiomatic solution. I suspect it's much more likely to be one of these two solutions:

1. Accept *only* `Maybe (Int, Int)`. Callers that have an `(Int, Int)` in hand can wrap it in a `Just`. (This solution can always be applied.)
2. Accept *only* `(Int, Int)`. Offer a default `(Int, Int)` -- say, `(0, 0)`, though of course the right choice depends on what the function does -- that callers can use if they have a `Maybe (Int, Int)` and its value is `Nothing`. (This solution is almost always possible, but in rare cases, the function might treat `Nothing` so specially that it cannot be emulated by any specific `(Int, Int)`.)